# What characters which were in use at the time were excluded from ASCII?

Tags: ascii

The [American Standard Code for Information Interchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a 7-bit character encoding.  Work on the standard began in 1960 and the first edition was published in 1963.  The standard attempted to include characters which were common in other character encodings (such as EBCDIC) and equipment (e.g. typewriters, printers, teletypes) at the time.

Which characters/symbols/glyphs which were in use by other encodings/equipment in 1963 or earlier didn't (*eventually*) make it into ASCII?

Because ASCII is an "American" code, non-English letters don't count.  Nor do things that were added in later versions of ASCII (e.g. curly brackets).

---

**Examples:** The cent sign ¢ was common on many typewriters and was bit pattern 100111 in the [FIELDATA character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIELDATA) used by UNIVAC and Unisys.

The square lozenge ⌑ was part of the first BCDIC character set in 1932, and continued to be used in its successor EBCDIC.  It was also used in the IBM 026 punched card code.

Comment: The request is way to broad to be answered in any useful fashion. There where hundrets of code sets already in use for various applications from teletypes to punch card machines.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The question isn't about codesets; it's about characters.

Comment: Err ... and what is the supposed meaning of _"were in use by other encodings/equipment"_  other than codeset(s)?

Comment: @Raffzahn: Find an example of a typewriter that has the double-percent symbol.  Or a teletype that has the square root symbol.  These characters never made it into ASCII.

Comment: If you want people to search typewrwriter keyboards, then say so, and exclude encodings. Somehow you now even contradict your own question - Now it would be even more apropriate to close it for being _"unclear what's asked at all"_

Comment: The question is both narrow and clear.  You want a question that no one else will be able to answer after you post your answer.  Be nice.

Comment: LOL. You mean beside that this spot is already taken by Janka's quite compact one? Instead of playing games, you should read your own question again and think about. You'r asking for Encodings, and then comment as it being not about Codesets but typewriters, right?  Not in any way consitent at all, or is it? So, instead of formulating unfounded attacks, what about investing some time in improving the question **and get the logic of what is asked straight**?

Comment: The Flexowriter was fairly common where I came from, and it had a good set of characters for representing Algol 60.  These include multiply, integer divide, logical and, logical or, logical not, etc. I exclude characters produced by overstriking, since that's a function of equipment, not coding (Flexo underscore conveniently did not move the print position).  [Here's a partial listing](https://ub.fnwi.uva.nl/computermuseum/X1flex.html#flexcod).

Comment: How about useful characters that were taken away in 1968?  Up arrow, left arrow.

Comment: If you include conventional "printing equipment", pretty much any glyph in any international language. Plus a large set of math symbols, etc. Plus hundreds of ligatures, for some alphabets (e.g. Greek). The question is neither narrow nor clear IMO.

Comment: @another-dave: Many teleprinters map 0x60-0x7F to 0x40-0x5F, and both the left arrow and underbar are sensible glyphs to use to represent a rub-out (place where a code was deleted from a tape).  I think underbar is probably more broadly useful, however.  Likewise, most places where up-arrow is useful could be served equally be caret, but caret offers additional usages.

Comment: The PDP-1 used some FIO-DEC codes in the 1960-1962 time frame. http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/PDP-1_alphanumeric_codes

Comment: Underbar also has the nice advantage of functioning as an underline. Plenty of programs used "print twice" for bold and "print underbar" for underline before dot-matrix printers & laser printers provided a way to print everything at once.

Comment: They never assigned a code to the DWIM key.  ;)

Answer (score 7):

Small letters. These were included in the 1967 ASCII standard but not the 1963 one.

Comment: [ASA X3.4-1963](http://worldpowersystems.com/ARCHIVE/codes/X3.4-1963/index.html) page 5. Codes 0x60-0x6F and 0x70-0x7B were unassigned. The American Standards Association became ANSI in 1969. See [The Evolution of Character Codes, 1874-1968](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.96.678) and [An annotated history of some character codes or ASCII: American Standard Code for Information Infiltration](http://worldpowersystems.com/ARCHIVE/codes/index.html) or [Coded Character Sets, History and Development](https://textfiles.meulie.net/bitsaved/Books/Mackenzie_CodedCharSets.pdf)

Comment: Notice the lower case characters *eventually* made it into the standard.

Comment: @user9041 ARE YOU SURE? NO ONE TOLD ME.

Answer (score 7):

The account, amount and routing characters from the [MICR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition) sets: CMC-7 (Groupe Bull, 1957) and E13B (ABA, 1958-59).

1963 ASCII also used to have `↑` and `←` where we now have `^` and `_`

Answer (score 5):

Some symbols in the [CDC display code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_display_code), while assigned ASCII counterparts, haven't gotten into ASCII by themselves, nor into the "near" ASCII extensions, like ¢ or ¤ (that's U+00A4 CURRENCY SIGN, not U+2311 SQUARE LOZENGE). For example, the ≡ character, code 48 in the CDC set, is now U+2261 IDENTICAL TO.

Answer (score 2):

The cents symbol was not in ASCII, was in IBM's EBCDIC, and therefore in keypunches, as mentioned the 026 and subsequent 029 and if I recall right the more automated 129